# How to specify max runtime using TensorFlow estimator with Python Sagemaker SDK?

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

Using the Python Sagemaker SDK, one can launch a training job using TensorFlow with the following code:

```
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

sess = sagemaker.Session()
tf_estimator = TensorFlow(...)
tf_estimator.fit(...)
```

Is it possible to specify the maximum runtime of the training somewhere in this script?

Answer (score 6):

Found an answer thanks to AWS support:

The TensorFlow estimator has as a base class `sagemaker.estimator.Framework` which in turn has as a base class `sagemaker.estimator.EstimatorBase` which accepts the parameter `train_max_run` which accepts a value in seconds and defaults to `86,400` or `24hs`.

So the initialization of the `TensorFlow` estimator to pass a custom value for maximum training runtime would look like:

```
MAX_TRAINING_TIME = 99999
tf_estimator = TensorFlow(..., train_max_run=MAX_TRAINING_TIME)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me add a small correction to the answer from @Franco.

`sagemaker.estimator.EstimatorBase`'s argument name is `max_run=86400` to assign maximum runtime.

Comment: Adding some more info: the answer from @Franco used to be correct, but as @t T s mentions, now it is max_run due to changes between versions